# Keep jumping out java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, encryption, netbeans-8

I'm trying out someone else AES file encryption/decryption program, but the problem is it keeps prompt and said that file is not found, but I did put the file in my netbean and put a directory but still not found. What the problem? Here is the code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;


public class AESEncryptor {

 public void encrypt(String fname) throws Exception{
  KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
  keyGen.init(256);  //using AES-256
  SecretKey key = keyGen.generateKey();  //generating key
  Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");  //getting cipher for AES
  aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);  //initializing cipher for         encryption with key

  //creating file output stream to write to file
  try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fname+".aes")){
   //creating object output stream to write objects to file
   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
   oos.writeObject(key);  //saving key to file for use during decryption

   //creating file input stream to read contents for encryption
   try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fname)){
    //creating cipher output stream to write encrypted contents
    try(CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, aesCipher)){
     int read;
     byte buf[] = new byte[4096];
     while((read = fis.read(buf)) != -1)  //reading from file
      cos.write(buf, 0, read);  //encrypting and writing to file
    }
   }
  }

 }

 public void decrypt(String fname)throws Exception{
  SecretKey key =null;

  //creating file input stream to read from file
  try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fname)){
   //creating object input stream to read objects from file
   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
   key = (SecretKey)ois.readObject();  //reading key used for encryption

   Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");  //getting cipher for AES
   aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);  //initializing cipher for     decryption with key
   //creating file output stream to write back original contents
   try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fname+".dec")){
    //creating cipher input stream to read encrypted contents
    try(CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, aesCipher)){
     int read;
     byte buf[] = new byte[4096];
     while((read = cis.read(buf)) != -1)  //reading from file
      fos.write(buf, 0, read);  //decrypting and writing to file
    }
   }
  }

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  AESEncryptor obj = new AESEncryptor();
 File file = new     File("C://Users/Jasmine/Documents/NetBeansProjects/testing/clear.txt");

  obj.encrypt(file.getName());
  obj.decrypt("clear.txt.aes");
 }

}
```

Comment: If the file exists and not able to read, then check the file permissions once. Try to give full permission and try to read it from the code.

Comment: Attach your error with the stacktrace. Should tell you exactly where the problem is and why.

Comment: I checked the permission its allowed for all user, but still can't find the file

Answer (score 2):

You are passing just the filename as argument to encrypt method, but as per the encrypt method, its expecting the complete path.
To be precise this line of code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fname)
```

Instead of :

```
obj.encrypt(file.getName());
```

Use this :

```
obj.encrypt(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Still prompt the same error


Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Jasmine\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testing\clear.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
 at AESEncryptor.encrypt(AESEncryptor.java:31)
 at AESEncryptor.main(AESEncryptor.java:73)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Do you have file at that location? Copy this path and open in explorer does the file open? Error msg is suggesting the file is not there.

Comment: Yup I able to open the file using the explorer, just don't know why it can't find the file in netbean

Comment: Well I don't see any problem reading the file using the above code (including the suggestion I gave). Try another thing, move file to an independent location and modify the code to read from there, maybe use folder: C:/tmp

Comment: Yeah its very weird, wondering it there something wrong with my system, I will try to solve this, thanks for your great help :)